# Problem rendering Custom Fonts on UE4 Text Render Component

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, fonts, blueprints

I have imported a TTF font on unreal engine. At first I just let unreal engine create the Font asset automatically, but when I try to create a material with that font it gives me a warning telling me that only offline fonts can be sampled. So I installed the font on my computer and set it to be cached offline.

[image: Font asset on editor]

On the editor, the font shows correctly and the preview shows the letters properly rendering. Unfortunately when I created a Text Render with this font, it shows only squares.

[image: Text render component]

I tried to create a material using the font as an opacity mask, but it renders the same result.